# Found errors in draft of researcher's book. Is it acceptable to ask for a review of my statement of purpose if I contact him regarding the errors?

Tags: statement-of-purpose

This researcher says something along the lines of "I welcome all contact regarding this book".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unless this is someone you know already, I'd say that you probably shouldn't ask. He's not offering unsolicited advice to all comers. You can either give him your feedback on his book or not, but I wouldn't tie the two things together.

Answer (score 8):

Oh no.  The operative phrase is "regarding this book."  You should ask for help with your statement from 1) your academic advisor, 2) a teacher you feel comfortable with, 3) a colleague who's gone through the process, 4) a friend who's an excellent writer, and so on.

Hitting this researcher up for advice is taking advantage of the situation.